# How to set up openView function that allows me to view my modal onClick?

Tags: javascript, php

I am currently working on a project that the user will display a modal, they fill out the data and the data is sent to the database. All of that is working fine but I want to include a function that when the user clicks on a column it will display the data within a modal as well. I have this set up within multiple tables on my jobs website but this is the first time I am doing it myself.

Currently this is how I have it setup:

```
function getTable() {
  mainDT = $('#mainTable').DataTable( {
    display: 'envelope',
    ajax: {
      'type': 'POST',
      'url': './ajax/getData.ajax.php',
      'data': {
        'getTable': 1,
    }
  },
  table: ('#mainTable'),
  orderCellsTop: true,
  searching: true,
  paging: true,
  bInfo: true,
  iDisplayLength: 50,
  scrollX: true,
  dom:
  "<'row'<'col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'l><'col-md-4 col-lg-6 d-none d-md-block'><'col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3'f>>" +
  "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
  "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
  columns: [
    { data: null, render: function ( data, type, row){

    //Here is where I am calling the viewFile function
      return "<a class=\"default-link\" onClick=\"viewFile(" + data.uid + ")\">" + data.createdby + "</a>";
      } 
    },
    { data: "itemold" },
    { data: "itemnew" },
    { data: "enddatetime" },
  ],
  fixedColumns: {
    leftColumns: 1
  },
  initComplete: function () {
    //This Draws the options for the table for static rows
    this.api().columns([0,1,2,3]).every( function () {
      var column = this;
      var select = $('<input type="text" class="fixed_col" placeholder="Search" />')
          .appendTo($(column.header()).parent().parent().children('tr').eq(1).children('th').eq(0).empty() )
          .on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );
            column
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
          }) ;
    } );
    }
  } );
  
  mainDT.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#mainTable_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');
        
  $( mainDT.table().container() ).on( 'keyup change clear', '.fixed_col', function () {
  mainDT
        .column( $(this).data('index') )
        .search( this.value )
        .draw();
  } );
  //Wait half a second for tables to finish and align columns
  setTimeout(fixColumns, 500, mainDT);
}
```

Here is where the viewFile function is:

```
var currentFile;
function viewFile(uid){
  $.ajax({
    url: './ajax/getData.ajax.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      "getFile": uid,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      openView(response);
   }
  });
}


var currentFile;
function openView(file){
  currentFile = file;

  for (var key in file) {
    if(key != 'uid') {
      if(file[key] !== '' && file[key] !== null){
        document.getElementById("view_" + key).innerHTML = file[key];
      } else {
        document.getElementById("view_" + key).innerHTML = "";
      }

      if(key != 'datetime' && key != 'createdby' && key != 'startdatetime' && key != 'enddatetime'){
        if(file[key] !== "" && file[key] !== null){
          $(".view_" + key).removeClass("hide");
        } else {
          $(".view_" + key).addClass("hide");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $("#viewModal").modal();

}
```

My backend code is here as well:

```
function getFile($uid){
  global $db;

  $query = "SELECT * FROM deviations WHERE uid=$uid";
  $results = basicQuery($query, $db);

  while($result = $results->fetch_assoc()){
    return $result;
  }
}
```

When I click on the link I get the error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')".

I know what the error means but don't know exactly how to fix it. So, what can I add to my code or what further debugging can I do that will allow me to further diagnose my problem?

Comment: Presumably then, `document.getElementById("view_" + key)` didn't find an element with the ID which results from concatenating `"view_"` with the value of `key`. So I suggest checking what value is being populated in `key` and then seeing if an element does or doesn't exist with that ID in the DOM at the time that code runs. As it's within a loop, you'll need to see on which iteration it's failing.